# Can I call store.subscribe method of redux in render() method of react component?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make an e-commerce store in meteor using **react** and **redux**. There is an icon in my navbar that displays total number of items added to the cart. I want to update the counter of items. If I call **store.getState().numOfItems** it displays total number of items added to the cart. but when I add an item to the cart, icon do not update. It only updates when I move onto other pages. (It's a **single page application** )

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have the store in your component, only the state.

Redux will update your components to match the current state, to put it simply.

You should use the [`connect()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function from react-redux to inject state and dispatchers in the component.

Overall, read the guide! http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html